# Download S3 file with a different filename than the bucket key

Tags: html, amazon-web-services, go, amazon-s3

I'm trying to change the name of a file I'm downloading from S3, but it keeps getting the bucket key as filename instead.

I'm using this function to get a Signed URL to download things from my S3 bucket.

```
func GetFileLink(url, filename string) (string, error) {
    svc := s3.New(some params)

    params := &s3.GetObjectInput{
        Bucket: aws.String(a bucket name),
        Key:    aws.String(key),
    }

    req, _ := svc.GetObjectRequest(params)
    req.SignedHeaderVals = make(map[string][]string)
    req.SignedHeaderVals.Add("Content-Disposition", "filename=the filename I want")
    str, err := req.Presign(15 * time.Minute)
    if err != nil {
        global.Log("[AWS GET LINK]:", params, err)
    }

    return str, err
}
```

And I'm using this in my HTML file to download the file with another name:

```
<a href="Link given by the function" download="the filename I want">Download the file.</a>
```

But I keep getting the file named as the bucket key. How can I change the name of the file being downloaded?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

According to the [Amazon GET Object Docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectGET.html), the parameter you need is actually `response-content-disposition`.

According to the [GetObjectInput](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/s3/#GetObjectInput) docs, `GetObjectInput` has a parameter to set the `ResponseContentDisposition` value.

Try:

```
params := &s3.GetObjectInput{
    Bucket: aws.String(a bucket name),
    Key:    aws.String(key),
    ResponseContentDisposition: "attachment; filename=the filename I want",
}

req, _ := svc.GetObjectRequest(params)
str, err := req.Presign(15 * time.Minute)
```

(Note: the usage of `SignedHeaderVals` is not required).

Thanks to michael for the correction to my original answer.

Comment: I removed the comment when I realized `req.SignedHeaderVals.Add` isn't the correct solution.  You're adding something related to a header -- not a query string parameter -- which is what `response-content-disposition` is.  `ResponseContentDisposition` needs to be passed as an argument to [`GetObjectInput`](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/blob/master/service/s3/api.go#L7495-L7570).  Feel free to take this info and revise your answer accordingly.

Comment: ...assuming you concur.  Docs for [GetObjectInput](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/s3/#GetObjectInput) says this "sets the header of the response" which is potentially misleading.  *Requests that S3 override the header in the response to this request* would be more precise, if this works the way it seems like it does.